# Desktop 12.04 gnome/cairo suddenly in Chinese

Tags: 12.04, language-support

After switching on my laptop Acer Aspire 5720Z, it is set to auto login to my native Dutch language. I was presented with a window to change the default folders name from Dutch to Chinese, canceled this, but everything is in Chinese. Managed to find and identify settings languages and move Dutch back to top and apply system-wide.

But wondering how Chinese got in there in the first place? I certainly didn't chose Chinese (even by mistake).

Comment: May be hack attempt, my server is hacked twice by Chinese people

Answer (score 0):

Add English language to your Ubuntu, it became Chinese because you may have erased English translation, your Dutch version are maybe not completely translated, so it displays English but if you don't have English anymore, Chinese pops up.